# ASP MVC 3: Is there a way to have an object in session expire after the user leaves the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following problem. In a view I have in ASP MVC where I need to store the original object that was received by the view and compare it to its modified version (which is the result after modifying the original object in the view).

The problem I have is that since the original object is not bound to the view (because there is no reason and I would have to create many hidden fields for this) then it is lost unless I store it in the Session. However, this can cause another problem because if the user leaves the page through the navigation menu instead of saving his changes this object will be left in session until it expires, which I think is not good.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that you're trying to reason in a "windows forms" or "web forms" way.

So you need to detect the changes made to your object. The pattern to achieve this is rather simple:

- Get your object from your datastore (whichever it is) and send it to the view
- Display the fields to edit your object. Have a single hidden field with the id of the object.
- Post the data to your action method. Retrieve the original object from the datastore using the id, then update the original object with the new values from your post.
- Persist your changes to the datastore.

As you see, no need to store anything in session. Other than being useless, it would be bad practice.

Comment: I was thinking in doing that, but I didn't like to hit the database for the second time since it is a collection and even though I don't think it will have more than 100 records I don't know how it could affect performance.

Comment: In web scenarios, all database contexts should be short-living, meaning open-dosomething-close every time. It's bad practice to have long-living stuff. You can find loads of information about this topic if you google a little. It's not a matter of what you like or not, really. It is a best practice to retrieve an object, close the connection, alter it, then retrieve the original with a new connection and update it. And you don't need to read the whole table, if you are doing it then you're doing wrong. Query only the object you're working with.

Comment: But that is what I am already doing I retrieve the object from the database and store it in memory. My connection is already closed when I received the object. What I don't want to do is to query the database again because even though in my current system it won't have a high impact in other projects that have a high transaction volume it would have. 

And if you read I am not having to query the whole table, but several records from it since the object is a collection so it is related to many rows in the database.

Comment: @groovejet: Since you cannot trust the object that came from the browser (e.g. it could have been tampered) you should consider re-reading it from the database as @Matteo suggested. Another approach would be to re-read the object from another server-side storage area but that's probably not much different than reading it from the database in the first place.

Comment: The object is not tampered it came from the database when the page is opened, so the user is not able to modify it. What I don't want to do is to query the database again in order to gather data that I already had initially.

Comment: I'm sorry, I already provided you with the commonly knows "Best Practice" for this scenario, I can't help you further, nor provide you with a solution that is recognised as bad practice.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you don't seem to be able to explain why it is a "Best Practice" and what I'm doing a "Bad Practice".

Comment: You asked a question, I provided an answer to that. For other related information (such as this) you can easily google for it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the original object in a database and retrieve it from there when the user posts the updated version?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a ViewBag? It is alive for only as long as you are on a particular view.